# how can I access "Name & Store's Name" from following json

Tags: javascript, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can access a specific value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-access-a-specific-value)

```
{
"List":
  [
     {"Active":true,"Name":"VMW","Stores":
      [
        {"Active":true,"Name":"Admin"},{"Active":true,"Name":"sunil"}
      ]
     }
  ]
}
```

Its json data, how can I read it using Ajax or Javasricpt

Comment: FYI, the expression "Ajax or Javascript" does not make much sense. "Ajax" is short for *Asynchronous JavaScript And XML*, i.e. Ajax is built on top of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

The List and the store is an array, so to retrieve name and store's name, use array index like this :

```
jsondata.List[0].Name >>> return "VMW"
jsondata.List[0].Stores[0].Name >>> return "Admin"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
json = {
"List":
  [
     {"Active":true,"Name":"VMW","Stores":
      [
        {"Active":true,"Name":"Admin"},{"Active":true,"Name":"sunil"}
      ]
     }
  ]
}

json["List"]  // { "Active":true,"Name":"VMW","Stores": [{"Active":true,"Name":"Admin"},{"Active":true,"Name":"sunil"}]}


json["List"][0]["Stores"] // {"Active":true,"Name":"Admin"},{"Active":true,"Name":"sunil"}
```

is Stores for Object

```
Stores = json["List"][0]["Stores"]

for (i in Stores) (function(active, name) {


    console.log(active, name);
}(Stores[i]["Active"], Stores[i]["Name"]));
```

for results:

```
true "Admin"
true "sunil"
```